# In R, how do I create a time histogram of intervals defined by a start and stop time for each entry?

Tags: r, histogram

I have a dataframe in which each row is the working hours of an employee defined by a start and a stop time:

```
DF < - EmployeeNum Start_datetime      End_datetime 
       123         2012-02-01 07:30:00  2012-02-01 17:45:00
       342         2012-02-01 08:00:00  2012-02-01 17:45:00
       876         2012-02-01 10:45:00  2012-02-01 18:45:00
```

I'd like to find the number of employees working during each hour on each day in a timespan:

```
Date       Hour  NumberofEmployeesWorking
2012-02-01 00:00 ? (number of employees working between 00:00 and 00:59)
2012-02-01 01:00 ?
2012-02-01 02:00 ?
2012-02-01 03:00 ?
2012-02-01 04:00 ?
2012-02-01 05:00 ?
2012-02-01 06:00 ?
```

How do I put my working hours into bins like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see @r2evans answer before posting. I came up with this independently, though it looks similar. I posted it here, so it may be helpful. Feel free to accept @r2evans answer.

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="EmployeeNum Start_datetime  End_datetime 
123  '2012-02-01 07:30:00'  '2012-02-01 17:45:00'
342  '2012-02-01 08:00:00'  '2012-02-01 17:45:00'
876  '2012-02-01 10:45:00'  '2012-02-01 18:45:00'", header = TRUE )

df1 <- within(df1, Start_datetime <- as.POSIXct( Start_datetime))
df1 <- within(df1, End_datetime <- as.POSIXct( End_datetime))
```

Code:

Find datetime sequence by 1 hour for each employee and count the number by `Start_datetime`.

Also, with this code, it is assumed that you separate original data by each single day and then apply the following code. If your data has multiple days mixed in it, with `IDateTime()` function from `data.table` package, it is possible to separate days from time and group by them while making the datetime sequence.

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df1)  # assign data.table class by reference
df2 <- df1[, Map( f = function(x, y) seq( from = trunc(x, "hour"), 
                                          to = round(y, "hour"),
                                          by = "1 hour" ),
                  x = Start_datetime, y = End_datetime  ),
           by = EmployeeNum ]

colnames(df2)[ colnames(df2) == "V1" ] <- "Start_datetime" # for some reason I can't assign column name properly during the column creation step.
```

Output:

```
df2[, .N, by = .( Start_datetime, End_datetime = Start_datetime + 3599 ) ]
#         Start_datetime        End_datetime N
# 1: 2012-02-01 07:00:00 2012-02-01 07:59:59 1
# 2: 2012-02-01 08:00:00 2012-02-01 08:59:59 2
# 3: 2012-02-01 09:00:00 2012-02-01 09:59:59 2
# 4: 2012-02-01 10:00:00 2012-02-01 10:59:59 3
# 5: 2012-02-01 11:00:00 2012-02-01 11:59:59 3
# 6: 2012-02-01 12:00:00 2012-02-01 12:59:59 3
# 7: 2012-02-01 13:00:00 2012-02-01 13:59:59 3
# 8: 2012-02-01 14:00:00 2012-02-01 14:59:59 3
# 9: 2012-02-01 15:00:00 2012-02-01 15:59:59 3
# 10: 2012-02-01 16:00:00 2012-02-01 16:59:59 3
# 11: 2012-02-01 17:00:00 2012-02-01 17:59:59 3
# 12: 2012-02-01 18:00:00 2012-02-01 18:59:59 3
# 13: 2012-02-01 19:00:00 2012-02-01 19:59:59 1
```

Graph:

`binwidth = 3600` the value indicates 1 hour = 60 min * 60 sec = 3600 seconds

```
library('ggplot2')
ggplot( data = df2,
        mapping = aes( x = Start_datetime ) )  +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 3600, color = "red", fill = "white" ) +
  scale_x_datetime( date_breaks = "1 hour", date_labels = "%H:%M" ) +
  ylab("Number of Employees") +
  xlab( "Working Hours: 2012-02-01" ) +
  theme( axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
         panel.grid = element_blank(),
         panel.background = element_rect( fill = "white", color = "black") )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your data, in a more consumable format, plus one row to span midnight (for example). I changed the format to include a "T" here, to make consumption easier, otherwise the middle space makes it less trivial to do it with `read.table(text='...')`. (You can skip this since you already have your real data.)

```
x <- read.table(text='EmployeeNum Start_datetime      End_datetime 
123         2012-02-01T07:30:00  2012-02-01T17:45:00
342         2012-02-01T08:00:00  2012-02-01T17:45:00
876         2012-02-01T10:45:00  2012-02-01T18:45:00
877         2012-02-01T22:45:00  2012-02-02T05:45:00',
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

In case you haven't done it with your own data, convert all times to `POSIXt`, otherwise skip this, too.

```
x[c('Start_datetime','End_datetime')] <- lapply(x[c('Start_datetime','End_datetime')],
                                                as.POSIXct, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

We need to generate a sequence of hourly timestamps:

```
startdate <- trunc(min(x$Start_datetime), units = "hours")
enddate <- round(max(x$End_datetime), units = "hours")
c(startdate, enddate)
# [1] "2012-02-01 07:00:00 PST" "2012-02-02 06:00:00 PST"

timestamps <- seq(startdate, enddate, by = "hour")
head(timestamps)
# [1] "2012-02-01 07:00:00 PST" "2012-02-01 08:00:00 PST" "2012-02-01 09:00:00 PST"
# [4] "2012-02-01 10:00:00 PST" "2012-02-01 11:00:00 PST" "2012-02-01 12:00:00 PST"
```

(Assumption: all end timestamps are *after* their start timestamps ...)

Now it's just a matter of tallying:

```
counts <- mapply(function(st,en) sum(st <= x$End_datetime & x$Start_datetime <= en),
                 timestamps[-length(timestamps)], timestamps[-1])

data.frame(
  start = timestamps[ -length(timestamps) ],
  count = counts
)
#                  start count
# 1  2012-02-01 07:00:00     2
# 2  2012-02-01 08:00:00     2
# 3  2012-02-01 09:00:00     2
# 4  2012-02-01 10:00:00     3
# 5  2012-02-01 11:00:00     3
# 6  2012-02-01 12:00:00     3
# 7  2012-02-01 13:00:00     3
# 8  2012-02-01 14:00:00     3
# 9  2012-02-01 15:00:00     3
# 10 2012-02-01 16:00:00     3
# 11 2012-02-01 17:00:00     3
# 12 2012-02-01 18:00:00     1
# 13 2012-02-01 19:00:00     0
# 14 2012-02-01 20:00:00     0
# 15 2012-02-01 21:00:00     0
# 16 2012-02-01 22:00:00     1
# 17 2012-02-01 23:00:00     1
# 18 2012-02-02 00:00:00     1
# 19 2012-02-02 01:00:00     1
# 20 2012-02-02 02:00:00     1
# 21 2012-02-02 03:00:00     1
# 22 2012-02-02 04:00:00     1
# 23 2012-02-02 05:00:00     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your answers. I came up with a solution which is pretty similar to yours, but I was wondering if you could have a look and let me know what you think of it.
I started a new empty dataframe, and then made two nested loops, to look at each start and end time in each row, and generate a sequence of hours in between. Then I each hour in the sequence to the new empty dataframe. This way, I can simply do a count later.

```
staffDetailHours <- data.frame("personnelNum"=integer(0),
                               "workDate"=character(0),
                               "Hour"=integer(0))
for (i in 1:dim(DF)[1]){
      hoursList <- seq(as.POSIXlt(DF[i,]$START)$hour,
                       as.POSIXlt(DF[i,]$END)$hour)
  for (j in 1:length(hoursList)) {
        staffDetailHours[nrow(staffDetailHours)+1,] = list(
        DF[i,]$EmployeeNum,
        DF[i,]$Date,
        hoursList[j]
        )
  }

}
```

Comment: Both of the answers so far use binning for an efficient calculation to feed your histogram; replacing that with two `for` loops is certainly ill-advised. (I suspect that this will scale poorly to any reasonable size of data.) Please do not post a comment or even another question as an answer to your previous question; if it is related, edit your original question; if it is not, then it needs to be another question.